# Everytime I make an SKSpriteNode a certain texture, the program crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I was in an sks scene file and tried making an object a texture, but it crashes each time I do it. I may be able to fix this programmatically, but I was wondering why this event kept occurring. Here's the specific error:

```
*** error for object 0x7fff33511200: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to have to post the code that causes this error.

Comment: Whatever you are doing no longer exists,  it is on it's way to being deleted, but has not been removed yet

Comment: @SteveIves I didn't add the object programmatically, I dragged them into the scene

Comment: So you have an empty project, you try to drag an object into the scene and then something (Xcode?) crashes? Or does it crash when you try to build and run? And you’ve added no code at all to the empty project?

Comment: @SteveIves I haven't built or ran it yet. I just drag it into the scene and it crashes in the editor.

Comment: Try restarting Xcode...

Comment: Oh this is only at the editor level?  it is still broken and buggy.